# How to select a row and handle the event in a Grid View on VB.NET 2.0

Tags: vb.net, gridview

Good evening,
i wish to be able to select a Grid View row and, when that happens, to trigger an event in the code behind so that i can handle it. I've tried using the event SelectedIndexChanged and SelectedIndexChanging and it never gets there. Is there any property that i need to set so that it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know you have to enable `autogenerateselectbutton = true`. [See more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanging.aspx)

```
<asp:GridVew id="Gridview1" 
   autogenerateselectbutton="True">

</asp:GridVew >
```

Event handler

```
 Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewSelectEventArgs)


       Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.SelectedRow

 End Sub
```

Comment: Even tho i don't want an extra column for this task...i'll take it. Thanks